# Is it bad design to have two models with many-to-many relationships also belong to the same parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I'm writing a bowling app with Players, Frames, and Throws.  Players have Frames and Throws.  A Frame has multiple Throws.  And a Throw can be associated with multiple Frames (for example, when a strike is thrown in a frame, subsequent throws need to be used for scoring in the strike frame).

My model looks like this:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :frames
  has_many :throws
end

class Frame < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  has_and_belongs_to_many :throws
end

class Throw < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  has_and_belongs_to_many :frames
end
```

Is it bad design to have the three all related like this?  Should I consider a different architecture?

Comment: I might be confused by semantics but does a throw actually have many frames?

Comment: A throw can be associated with many frames.  For example, frame 1 could be a strike.  Then a throw for frame 2 would be associated with frame 1 as well because frame 1 needs to know about it in order to calculate the score for frame 1.  Frames need to know about future frame's throws basically.

Comment: Out of personal / organizational preference I would probably give it the context of a game. Then a throw doesn't need many frames...you can reference the last throw by accessing the previous frame.

Comment: I actually do have a Game as well.  A Game has many Players.  The Throw would still need to be associated with multiple Frames so the Frame knows how to score itself.

Now I'm wondering if I can just have the Frame reference other Frames.  Then it can look ahead to future frames by the same player and calculate it's own score without having to have throws be associated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use simpler structure to fulfill your requirements. Using the following structure you can track throws of each frame and frames of each player.

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :frames
end

class Frame < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  has_many :throws
end

class Throw < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :frame
end
```

Or if you need to track throws and frames of particular player separately, and furthermore need has_many association of frames and throws with each other. You can do as follows:

```
class Frame < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :throws, through: :players
end

class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :frame
  belongs_to :throw
end

class Throw < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :frames, through: :players
end
```